# How can I force a number in python to take 32 bits instead of 64 bits

Tags: python, integer

So, what I understand is that in a 64 bit system, a number declared in python takes 64 bits. Is it possible to make it 32 bit, for memory reduction purposes?

Comment: What kind of number, and using what libraries? E.g. in `numpy` you can get very specific with `dtype`, but e.g. vanilla `int` (`long` in 2.x) are unlimited-precision.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Here's an old SO question about finding the size of variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372006/variables-memory-size-in-python

Comment: Python integers are not '32 bit' or '64 bit'. They are Python integers. What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: Python uses [arbitrary-precision integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), the bit width of the integer grows when needed to hold large integers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of numbers that need to be stored, you could use `array.array('l')` or `array.array('L')`. You may also use `ctypes.c_int()`, `ctypes.c_uint()`, `ctypes.c_long()`, or `ctypes.c_ulong()` to store numbers in four bytes.