# Jupyter Notebook List Python Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Can someone explain how I can see all python dataframes in my Jupyter Notebook kernal occupying my memory?

For context in Spyder IDE, I can see all variables ive assigned within it.

Outcome:
Id like to see a list of ones still sitting in my memory and by how much ram they are occuying. % of total would be nice as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372006/variables-memory-size-in-python/14372035 This might help you

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
%whos DataFrame
```

Comment: I thought this would have worked too but i get the message :  "No variables match your requested type."

Comment: Are you using pandas dataframes?