# Python memory limit

Tags: python, memory

So clearly there cannot be unlimited memory in Python. I am writing a script that creates lists of dictionaries. But each list has between 250K and 6M objects (there are 6 lists).

**Is there a way to actually calculate (possibly based on the RAM of the machine) the maximum memory and the memory required to run the script?**

## The actual issue I came across:

In running one of the scripts that populates a list with 1.25-1.5 million dictionaries, when it hits 1.227... it simply stops, but returns no error let alone `MemoryError`. So I am not even sure if this is a memory limit. I have print statements so I can watch what is going on, and it seems to buffer forever as nothing is printing and up until that specific section, the code is running a couple thousand lines per second. **Any ideas as to what is making it stop? Is this memory or something else?**

Comment: You'd have to look at what objects you store in each list, and how much space it takes. `sys.getsizeof` should get you started

Comment: each object in this specific list returns `72` from `sys.getsizeof(object)`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget how can I use this information to determine why this is stopping. I have 4GB of RAM if that makes any difference.

Comment: @RyanSaxe: What OS are you using? How much memory is still available to processes?

Comment: If the dictionaries all have the same keys, you can save a lot of memory by using namedtuples

Comment: @RyanSaxe: the 72 bytes is **just** the dict object, not it's contents. You'll have to get the size of the keys and the values too.

Comment: If it runs using a 64-bit version of Python, then yeah, it's a memory problem.

Comment: What exactly does "it simply stops" mean? That the process terminates? Or merely that it stops making visible *progress*? The latter is very common when you're pushing your RAM limit, as the OS spends huge gobs of time swapping out other programs to disk (to free up a little more RAM).  This *can* go on for - literally - hours before finally getting a `MemoryError` (although that's unusual, it's certainly possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that many objects you need to store, you need store them on disk, not in memory. **Consider using a database**.

If you import the `sys` module you will have access to the function [`sys.getsizeof()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof). You will have to look at each object of the list and for each dictionary compute the value for every key. For more on this see this previous question - [In-memory size of a Python structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331471/in-memory-size-of-python-stucture).