# Python List size limitation

Tags: python

As I am new to python could any one tell me what is the maximum memory size that a list in python can accommodate.
a = [1,2,3,45]
For instance let size of 'a' be 10 bytes.
So I would like to know how many such bytes can be the maximum limit for the list.
Does it in anyway depend on RAM?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `print sys.maxsize` gives an indication.

Comment: There is also [getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) that can be useful to check memory usage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python memory limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102429/python-memory-limit)

Comment: @MarounMaroun, you are right, see [repo](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Objects/listobject.c#l51). Perhaps you'd like to make it an actual answer. It's not like the memory is the limit, it's the counter causing overflow that can also trigger `MemoryError`.

Comment: I have 16gb RAM, and doing `>>> a = [0]*2000000000` occupies 14.9gb. Refer here for the limits - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get

Comment: Don't confuse RAM with virtual memory!  Very few programs write explicitly to RAM, certainly Python does not.  RAM size is not irrelevant but is more likely to affect performance (paging) than limits.  How Python handles memory depends on the operating system and on the Python version.