# python: Why memory space of a object will increase when object converted int to bytearray?

Tags: python, object, memory

I am confused :

(1) when int convert to bytearray (or str convert to bytearray) ,why its memory space increase ?

```
a=1  # int 
print 'space of int ',sys.getsizeof(a)
b=bytearray(a) # convert
print 'space of b ',sys.getsizeof(b)

s='h' # str 
print 'space of s',sys.getsizeof(s)
b2=bytearray(s)
print 'space of b2',sys.getsizeof(b2)
```

output:

```
space of a  12
space of b  26
space of s 22
space of b2 26
```

(2) I have read this ,
[In-memory size of a Python structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331471/in-memory-size-of-python-stucture)
and I have known  different types of a python object  has different memory size.But I can't figure out its principle.

Comment: Presumably it is due to different amounts of overhead for the two types.  However, note that `bytearray(1)` does not create a bytearray containing the bytes of the integer 1; it creates a bytearray containing a single zero byte.  Be sure to read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray).

Comment: "If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes." thank you ~

Answer (score 1):

Every Python type has a minimal amount of space it will use, even if empty.  This is commonly called the *overhead*.

Container datatypes (`dict`, `list`, `tuple`, `bytearray`, `set`, etc.) will typically have more overhead than simple types (`str`, `int`, etc.) because there is more to keep track of (size, pointers to elements, etc.).