# How to get ROS MSG length in python?

Tags: python, message, ros

I have a problem that needs to count the length of each ROS topic msg.

I modified rostopic(/opt/ros/smart-ros/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic / __ init__.py):

```
Class CallbackEcho(object) ->
Def callback (self, data, callback_args, current_time = None):
    Print('message length =',sys.getsizeof(data)) #statics msg length
```

But when the message contains a vector or struct list, the length is incorrect.

Please help solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: rosmsg show XXXX/XXXX
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
bool a
float64 c
float64 m
float64 g

but the message length is 96.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the "length" of a message. Do you mean if the message has a vector on it, you want to know how many elements are in it? In any event, you shouldn't be monkeying with the ROS source code, there is probably a way to do what you want in some client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the behaviour of [sys.getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

This means only the size of the reference to a list is used to calculate the object size.

There are already a few questions dealing with this:

- [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)
- [In-memory size of a Python structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331471/in-memory-size-of-a-python-structure)

The solution is to **use [Pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/) and its module [asizeof](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/asizeof.html#asizeof)** which provides a function to the required calculation:

> Function asizeof calculates the combined (approximate) size of one or several Python objects in bytes

After installing the package using *pip*

> pip install pympler

and importing it to your code like

```
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
```

you are able to print the correct object size in your callback like

```
print('Size: ' + str(asizeof(data)))
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, but my python version is 2.7.
nvidia@p22:~$ pip install pympler
Collecting pympler
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pympler (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pympler
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: nvidia@p22:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: My answer is compatible with Python 2.7. You need to upgrade pip and install Pympler.

Comment: Thank you in advance, pympler was installed successfully.
pip upgrade failed，Use this command：
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org Pympler

Comment: I have some doubts. I would like to ask some specific questions. Can you leave a mailbox?

Comment: So what are your doubts? Extend your question, comment or think about asking a new question.

Comment: def callback(self, data, callback_args, current_time=None):
        print('asizeof(data)=', asizeof(data))
        print ('data.__sizeof__()=', data.__sizeof__())
        print ('len(str(data))=', len(str(data)))
        print ('sys.getsizeof(data)=', sys.getsizeof(data))

asizeof(data)= 114696
data.__sizeof__()= 64
len(str(data))= 72327
sys.getsizeof(data)= 96

Comment: In fact, asizeof (data) is bigger than len (str (data)), is it correct?