# Single, concise desription of Python's memory model/execution environment?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

When I learned C/C++ I not only learned the syntax of the language and the semantics of the language constructs but also how the program was executed by the computer.  I learned stuff like:

> All local variables are declared in a stack frame, which is allocated
>   each time the function is called.  These frames are laid out on the
>   call stack one right after the other, and they're 'unwound' when the
>   function returns, thus quickly and efficiently 'destroying' the local
>   variables for that function

This, in turn, helped me figure out why it's a bad idea to take the address of a local variable & return it to the calling function.  In other words, understanding C/C++'s memory model and the environment in which the code executes helps develop a deeper understanding of how to write correct programs.

Another example: malloc/new allocate objects in the 'heap' (and not the stack), which both explains why they live beyond the end of the function that allocated them.  Further, knowing that these functions/keywords return the memory address that the object is located at helped me to understand how things like linked lists work. (And how to figure out whether I need another `*` or `->` or not.)

So now I'm learning Python and **I'm looking for a concise, clear, yet thorough explanation of how Python programs manage their memory and execution environment**.

Searching online hasn't been particularly fruitful - I might be using the wrong search terms, but there appears to be very little out there in general.

I've looked through https://docs.python.org/ and found it to be an excellent resource for syntax and semantics ("if you type X, then Y will happen"), but it doesn't really describe what the computer is doing 'under the hood'.

I've found several posts here on Stack Overflow ( such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468764/understanding-pythons-memory-model), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059674/python-memory-model), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604974/python-memory-model-for-this-program) ) but these all seem to focus on specific situations.

**Does anyone know of a resource that actually explains what Python is doing under the hood'?**

> EDIT: I'm getting feedback from StackOverflow that this question may
>   be a duplicate.  [The other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299648/python-compilation-interpretation-process) asks 'how does a .PY file get
>   compiled (to bytecode) and then executed by the VM?'  What I'm asking
>   here is 'is there a page that explains how Python lays variables,
>   objects, functions, etc out in memory AND explains how that's all used
>   to actually run Python programs' (Sub-question: Is this an appropriate
>   way to address the concern about a duplicate question?  Would it be
>   better to put this in a comment?)

Comment: python is actually written in C so you would be able to get the source code for the language itself and read through it if that would help you understand how it works.

Comment: You may also find [this Programmers question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/246094/143097) helpful.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html?highlight=garbage%20collection#how-does-python-manage-memory has some pointers

Comment: are you looking for something like this?   You can get information about an objects memory location using the `id` builtin but there is no way to directly access an object by its id, instead the interpreter keeps track of how many references exist for a particular object and when there are no more references that object gets garbage collected which calls its `__del__` method for it to clean up it's resources such as a file closing the open io.

Comment: Thanks, @llja!  That's exactly the sort of thing that I'm looking for!
This sentence in particular seems to explain why there's no real documentation about how things are implemented:
_The details of Python memory management depend on the implementation_.
It's interesting, though - they've got a question about 'how is a list implemented' below that which explains that it's a resizable array (and NOT a linked list), so it does seem like it's possible to know something about the implementation...

Comment: A list is guaranteed to be backed by a resizable array. What the page refers to is that the low-level memory management works by reference counting with cycle collector in CPython and Java GC in Jython.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - where did you learn that?  Did you look for that in particular, was it something that you stumbled across, or maybe there was a page somewhere that talks about how data types, stack frames, objects, arrays, etc, etc, are stored in Python?

Comment: No page in particular; stackoverflow, reading the docs here and there, and reading the C and Java source code :D

Comment: Start by reading the FAQ linked by @Ilja and the Python data model from Paul Evans' answer.

Answer (score 1):

With python what you want to know about what's going on under the hood straight away to be able to work efficiently with the language is quite different from C/C++ since it's a quite different language environment.  What you want to get you head around is not so much the nitty-gritty of what's going on memory, but [Python's Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: While this is a link only answer that doesn't really answer the original question, I completely agree that understanding the Data Model will help with python more than understanding the memory management.